# Serial connection is not working.(overrun(s))

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, serial-port, gps

I am trying to synchronize the time by connecting the GPS module. I have already checked the time synchronization using the USB port.

However, when I try to connect the GPS module to the serial port on the Raspberry device, it does not boot (load ubuntu on the Raspberry device), and after booting, connect the GPS module to the serial port, and it comes out of dmesg as follows.

```
2031.019236] Bluetooth: hci0: Malicious advertising data. Stopping processing
[ 2031.221116] Bluetooth: hci0: Malicious advertising data. Stopping processing
[ 2031.228329] ttyS ttyS0: 8 input overrun(s)
[ 2031.228368] Bluetooth: hci0: Malicious advertising data. Stopping processing
[ 2031.241763] Bluetooth: hci0: Malicious advertising data. Stopping processing
[ 2031.454953] Bluetooth: hci0: Malicious advertising data. Stopping processing
[ 2031.931220] Bluetooth: hci0: Malicious advertising data. Stopping processing
[ 2031.952123] Bluetooth: hci0: Malicious advertising data. Stopping processing
[ 2032.269392] Bluetooth: hci0: Malicious advertising data. Stopping processing
[ 2032.276590] ttyS ttyS0: 4 input overrun(s)
[ 2032.346935] Bluetooth: hci0: Malicious advertising data. Stopping processing
[ 2057.431690] Bluetooth: hci0: Malicious advertising data. Stopping processing
[ 2057.438903] ttyS ttyS0: 2 input overrun(s)
[ 2057.462867] Bluetooth: hci0: Malicious advertising data. Stopping processing
[ 2057.470119] Bluetooth: hci0: Malicious advertising data. Stopping processing
[ 2057.494830] Bluetooth: hci0: Malicious advertising data. Stopping processing
[ 2057.502074] Bluetooth: hci0: Malicious advertising data. Stopping processing
[ 2057.509272] Bluetooth: hci0: Malicious advertising data. Stoppin
```

Basically, ble scanning is in operation. Why can't serial data be collected? Is there a conflict with the ble scanning operation?

ubuntu os :

```
user@ubuntu:~$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: ubuntu
         Icon name: computer
        Machine ID: efe379259a0b4420aca69ae4f842f8ba
           Boot ID: 50619f4f4639480b9c42cdb59a15e2e3
  Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-1056-raspi
      Architecture: arm64
```

Comment: Hello. I am not seeing how this is a Ubuntu OS issue. Can you inquire of whom ever makes this device if it is even supported?

Comment: You're spending too much of some resource (CPU, Interrupt controller, Bluetooth starting and stopping) to receive THIS byte from the serial device before the NEXT byte arrives. Either fix the Bluetooth issue, OR configure the.GPS to use a lower baud rate, OR both.